# What is wrong with this code? I am getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I am getting runtime error, what is the fault in this?
On removing if(Px[size-1].ele>a) error goes away!
I tried using while only when i is zero and still I got the error!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define f(i,n) for(i=0;i<n;i++)
#define f1(i,n)    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
#define ll long long
#define ld long double
#define MOD 1000000007
typedef struct{
    int ele;
    int pos;
    int sum;
} vj;
int main()
{
    int n,size,sum,i,a;
    vj Px[1000000];
    cin>>n;
    size=sum=0;
    f(i,n){
        cin>>a;
        sum+=a;
        while(size){
            if(Px[size-1].ele>a)
                break;
            size--;
        }
        Px[size].ele=a;
        Px[size].pos=i+1;
        Px[size].sum=sum;
        size++;
    }
    //sum=P[0].ele*P[0].pos-P[0].sum;
    //f(i,size-1)
    //    sum+=(P[i+1].ele*(P[i+1].pos-P[i].pos))-(P[i+1].sum-P[i].sum);
    //cout<<size<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What has stepping the program through a debugger told you?

Comment: Why do you use those ugly obscuring macros?

Comment: 12M+ in local variables? No wonder things break.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the `if(Px[size-1].ele>a)` line, and tell us that size == 0 during one iteration.

Comment: Code depends on user input and I can't see what you type. Try a debugger and check line error and variable values. Also erase that ugly macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct{
    int ele;
    int pos;
    int sum;
} vj;


int main() {
  vj Px[1000000];
  ...
```

this is a **stack overflow**. MSVC has a default limit of 1 MB stack size. You're *crumbling* that limit.

I suggest using a heap allocation instead of relying on stack local variables of that size.

Comment: At 12x 1MB for that one local variable, that's a bit more than hitting it.

Comment: It's kind of "breaking it completely"

Comment: @Deduplicator He's "pummeling" the limit.

Comment: @MarcoA. Perhaps you should suggest an alternative, e.g. using a global variable or malloc().